# Basic Password Hashing Grails

Tags: grails, password-encryption

I am currently playing around with Grails, and I am making a basic login and session system (just for fun).

I currently have a form on a webpage that reads a username and password and sends them into a controller. This is currently what the code in the controller looks like:

```
def login = {

  String inputPassword = params.password

if(params.username == "admin" && inputPassword == "changeme"){
  flash.message = "login succeed";
    session.user = "admin"
    }
else{
    flash.message = "login failed"
    }

  redirect(action: 'index')

}

  def logout = {
  session.user = null
  redirect(action: 'index')

}
```

Now, I know it is a bad idea to store passwords in raw text, so I would like to play around with hashing the password.

I would assume this block of code that takes the input from the password field and assigns it to the variable inputPassword:

```
 String inputPassword = params.password
```

Can be changed to look something like this with some sort of API:

```
String inputPassword = aHashOf(params.password)
```

and the check step can look like this:

```
 if(params.username == "admin" && inputPassword == (whatever the final hash looks like) )
```

Is there an API or built in function that can help me with this? Am I trying to go around this the wrong way? Any suggestions?

Also, later, when I learn to use databases, can this process be easily changed to use database values?

Answer (score 2):

Although it seems reasonable to implement something like this by yourself to learn the basics of how authentication & authorization works, for real use-cases is seems more realistic to use a framework / library for this.

In the Java/Spring world (where grails is a part of) there has been [spring-security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) with its grails plugin [spring-security-core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) as well as [apache shiro](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro). The [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/) of the plugin should give you a good starting point how to use the api of spring security.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info, I have read up a little on this, but I don't seem to have a BuildConfig.groovy to add the compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4' too. Is the process for installing plugins different in GRails 3.0?

Comment: Well, for grails 3 i don't think there is a clear solution like pointing to the spring security plugin. The problem is, that grails 3 is pretty new, so the some major plugins are lacking of support for grails 3 (like spring security). But, since grails 3 is based on spring boot, certain "plugins" / starter poms from boot are available to grails. For spring-security you can take a look at blog posts like [this](http://spiesdavid.blogspot.de/2015/03/grails-3-app-with-security-part-1.html) or a [github example](https://github.com/asoftwareguy/grails3-spring-security-demo).